# Enviar newsletter

Tags: banco-de-dados, email, asp, newsletter

Estou a tentar enviar uma *newsletter* a todos os utilizadores que têm activa a *newsletter* e não estou a conseguir.

O meu código de enviar um *email* normal é:

```
try
{
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  smtp.Port = 587;
  smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("msg@gmail.com", "msg");
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;

  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
  msg.Subject = "msg | Newsletter | " + txtAssunto.Text + " - msg";
  msg.Body = "Msg";
  string toAddress = ????
  msg.To.Add(toAddress);

  string fromAddress = "\"msg";
  msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
  msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
  smtp.Send(msg);

} catch {

}
```

Como posso fazer para ir buscar à base de dados todos os *mails* cujo têm *newsletter* activa, ou seja `SELECT EMAIL FROM UTILIZADORES WHERE NEWSLETTER = 'TRUE'`.

Como posso fazer isso, para que o `msg.To.Add(toAddress);` só envie *mails* para os *users* com *newsletter* activa?

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples de fazer isso seria realizar uma consulta no banco com essa sua query e usar o retorna a lista/array retornado pra preencher o addRecipient. No exemplo abaixo estou usando o jdbc e o postgres, mas você pode usar qualquer banco.

```
try {
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host:porta/database";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"usuario","senha");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;

    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT EMAIL FROM UTILIZADORES WHERE NEWSLETTER = \'TRUE\'");
    List<String> enderecos = new LinkedList<String>();
    while ( rs.next() ) {
        enderecos.add(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
    }
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

e colocar o retorno em um array ou uma lista (a preferência é sua). E no seu código, você pode utilizar o método .addRecipient do seu objeto Message. Por exemplo:

```
for (String email : enderecos){
    message.addRecipient(Message.Recipient-type.CC, InternetAddress.parse(email));
}
```

Comment: Poderia exemplificar de uma forma mais complexa? Já tentei de várias formas mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Em qual parte você está tendo dificuldades?

Comment: Na selecção dos emails dos usuários que têm a newsletter activa. Já tentei de várias formas dentro do try e não consegui. Tentei pôr o sql command em string to address e também não funcionou assim.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, vê agora se a resposta está mais clara.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de fazer via stored procedure?